# How to switch back and forth between two different sections on a sprite sheet while user still holds a key using SFML

Tags: c++, time, sprite, sfml, sprite-sheet

So my only goal here is to move the sprite left and right, and while the sprite is moving, I want to switch between two different parts of my sprite sheet every half a second.

I've tried everything I could think of so I left it working and without only the implementation of the needed feature. (EDIT: I've changed it in an attempt to try to follow advice given by another user) I've looked online, but nothing I could find answered my question as far as I could tell. I'm sure there's something I'm overlooking and that it is quite simple, but that's why I need your input.

The third parts of the sprite sheet I want to use is at x = 800, animations facing left are on top at y = 0, and the animations facing right are on bottom at y = 600

[Here is the sprite sheet I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCd0f.png)

The first ones are for standing still, and the second two on either row are the ones I want to switch between while "walking"

At any rate, here is my code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <random>
#include <unordered_map>

enum State 
{
    Walking,
    Standing
};
enum Direction
{
    Left,
    Right
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    /* Gregory */

    sf::Texture GregorySpriteSheet_T;
    GregorySpriteSheet_T.loadFromFile("Images/GregorySpriteSheet.png");
    sf::IntRect GregorySpriteRect(0, 600, 400, 600);
    sf::Sprite Gregory(GregorySpriteSheet_T, GregorySpriteRect);

    sf::RenderWindow renderWindow(sf::VideoMode(1600,800), "SFML 2 Demo");

    sf::Event event;



    sf::Time timePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.0f / 60.0f);
    sf::Clock deltaClock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;


    State isWalking{ Standing };
    sf::Clock walkClock;
    Direction direction = Right;




    /* RENDER WINDOW LOOP */


    while (renderWindow.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Time deltaTime = deltaClock.restart();
        timeSinceLastUpdate += deltaTime;

        while (timeSinceLastUpdate >= timePerFrame)
        {
            timeSinceLastUpdate -= timePerFrame;



            while (renderWindow.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
                {
                    renderWindow.close();
                }


                if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed)
                {
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
                    {
                        isWalking = Walking;
                        direction = Right;
                    }

                }
                if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyReleased)
                {
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
                    {
                        isWalking = Standing;
                    }

                }


                if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed)
                {
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                    {
                        isWalking = Walking;
                        direction = Left;

                    }
                }
                if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyReleased)
                {
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                    {
                        isWalking = Standing;

                    }
                }
            }



            if (isWalking == Walking)
            {
                if (direction == Right)
                    GregorySpriteRect.top = 600;
                if (direction == Left)
                    GregorySpriteRect.top = 0;

                if (GregorySpriteRect.left == 0)
                    GregorySpriteRect.left = 400;

                if ((int(walkClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() / 1.5f) % 2) == 1)
                {
                    if (GregorySpriteRect.left == 400)
                        GregorySpriteRect.left == 800;
                    if (GregorySpriteRect.left == 800)
                        GregorySpriteRect.left == 400;
                    walkClock.restart();
                }
            }

            {
                using kb = sf::Keyboard;

                    if (kb::isKeyPressed(kb::Right))
                    {
                        Gregory.move(400 * timePerFrame.asSeconds(), 0.0f);
                        direction = Right;
                        isWalking = Walking;
                    }


                    if (kb::isKeyPressed(kb::Left))
                    {
                        Gregory.move(-400 * timePerFrame.asSeconds(), 0.0f);
                        direction = Left;
                        isWalking = Walking;
                    }

                    if (kb::isKeyPressed(kb::Right) && kb::isKeyPressed(kb::Left))
                    {
                        isWalking = Standing;
                    }

            }


            if (isWalking == Standing)
            {
                GregorySpriteRect.left = 0;

                if (direction == Right)
                    GregorySpriteRect.top = 600;
                if (direction == Left)
                    GregorySpriteRect.top = 0;
            }

        }




        Gregory.setTextureRect(GregorySpriteRect);

        renderWindow.clear();
        renderWindow.draw(Gregory);
        renderWindow.display();

    }
                /* END RENDER WINDOW LOOP */



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anybody that winds up here in the future, I was missing a vital line:

```
Gregory.setTextureRect(GregorySpriteRect);
```

Either in my "if" statement for the clock under the "if (isWalking == Walking)", or under it (like I've done here). Pasted the full code below. Works for both directions now. Not sure how optimal this is but if you're an amateur like me this should help.

Also mind that I've reverted back some of the changes suggested from Botje's answer. Although I must credit him for helping me very much with the recommendation of using enum's for Walking and Standing, as well as direction. I also used a ">" operator rather than the "==" operator as suggested by my professor due to rounding errors of float point variables.

Cheers!

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <random>
#include <unordered_map>

enum State 
{
    Walking,
    Standing
};
enum Direction
{
    Left,
    Right
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    /* Gregory */

    sf::Texture GregorySpriteSheet_T;
    GregorySpriteSheet_T.loadFromFile("Images/GregorySpriteSheet.png");
    sf::IntRect GregorySpriteRect(0, 600, 400, 600);
    sf::Sprite Gregory(GregorySpriteSheet_T, GregorySpriteRect);

    sf::RenderWindow renderWindow(sf::VideoMode(1600,800), "SFML 2 Demo");

    sf::Event event;



    sf::Time timePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.0f / 60.0f);
    sf::Clock deltaClock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;


    State isWalking{ Standing };
    sf::Clock walkClock;
    Direction direction = Right;




    /* RENDER WINDOW LOOP */


    while (renderWindow.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Time deltaTime = deltaClock.restart();
        timeSinceLastUpdate += deltaTime;

        while (timeSinceLastUpdate >= timePerFrame)
        {
            timeSinceLastUpdate -= timePerFrame;



            while (renderWindow.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
                {
                    renderWindow.close();
                }


                if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed)
                {
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
                    {
                        isWalking = Walking;
                        direction = Right;
                        GregorySpriteRect.top = 600;
                    }

                }
                if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyReleased)
                {
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right)
                    {
                        isWalking = Standing;
                    }

                }


                if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed)
                {
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                    {
                        isWalking = Walking;
                        direction = Left;
                        GregorySpriteRect.top = 0;

                    }
                }
                if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyReleased)
                {
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left)
                    {
                        isWalking = Standing;
                    }
                }
            }



            if (isWalking == Walking)
            {
                if (direction == Right)
                    GregorySpriteRect.top = 600;
                else if (direction == Left)
                    GregorySpriteRect.top = 0;
                else 
                    GregorySpriteRect.top = 600;

                if (GregorySpriteRect.left == 0)
                    GregorySpriteRect.left = 400;

                if (walkClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 0.5f)
                {
                    if (GregorySpriteRect.left == 400)
                        GregorySpriteRect.left = 800;
                    else if (GregorySpriteRect.left == 800)
                        GregorySpriteRect.left = 400;
                    else
                        GregorySpriteRect.left += 0;

                    walkClock.restart();
                }

                Gregory.setTextureRect(GregorySpriteRect);

            }

            {
                using kb = sf::Keyboard;

                    if (kb::isKeyPressed(kb::Right))
                    {
                        Gregory.move(400 * timePerFrame.asSeconds(), 0.0f);
                        direction = Right;
                    }


                    if (kb::isKeyPressed(kb::Left))
                    {
                        Gregory.move(-400 * timePerFrame.asSeconds(), 0.0f);
                        direction = Left;
                    }

                    if (kb::isKeyPressed(kb::Right) && kb::isKeyPressed(kb::Left))
                    {
                        isWalking = Standing;
                        direction = Right;
                    }

            }


            if (isWalking == Standing)
            {
                GregorySpriteRect.left = 0;

                if (direction == Right)
                    GregorySpriteRect.top = 600;
                if (direction == Left)
                    GregorySpriteRect.top = 0;
            }

        }




        Gregory.setTextureRect(GregorySpriteRect);

        renderWindow.clear();
        renderWindow.draw(Gregory);
        renderWindow.display();

    }
                /* END RENDER WINDOW LOOP */



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one suggestion, but there are plenty of alternatives:

First, rewrite your event handling slightly such that you can differentiate between the first time a key is held and subsequent times. A simple way is to have an `enum State { Standing, Walking }` and set it to the appropriate value in your key handler (eg "not walking and key is held? set state to walking")

Then, when the player starts walking, (re)start a "walk" clock.

Finally, when you are actually rendering your player, check this clock and divide the expired time since walking by your walking period (this determines how long one of the walking frames should be held). If there were an even number of such walking periods, use the left walking sprite, otherwise the right walking sprite.

This technique easily generalizes to larger sets of walking frames, of course.

Comment: I have updated my code to try to best fit my understanding of your advice, but I'm afraid I still don't get the 'switching' I want. I think my method of trying to switch back and forth that I put at the end near the rendering calls may be my issue. Its the only way I can come up with getting the task done, save for maybe a couple minor changes that simply calculate the same result differently (i.e. +=400 instead of 400 now equals 800 or vice versa)

If not that then I believe I simply don't have a good enough understanding of where and how exactly to use the clock for this task.

Comment: I think you need to move the isWalking state and walkClock up one more level: that `renderWindow.isOpen()` loop runs once per frame, while you want this state to persist across frames. Additionally, you only need to restart `walkClock` on the *transition* from Standing to Walking, so inside the "if keyPressed" and "if keyReleased" bits. Finally, I think the test you want is `int(walkClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() / 0.5f) % 2 == 1`. This will alternate every half second.

Comment: Hey again, unfortunately after messing with the code for some hours racking my brain and trying to do what you said, I still have the same result.
I understand you may have better things to do but I think I've really come to a standstill in learning this here. I learned to switch parts of the sprite sheet while not pressing any keys, but I don't see what good that does me if I can't do the same while the user is holding a key

Comment: I should also mention I edited the code in the post again to my last attempt before coming back